# Rotating a parent gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I know this question is a duplicate but I’ve tried all the other solutions and can’t find a way to work this out. I have a bunch of cubes set up in unity in a circle, and my goal is to rotate them collectively when someone holds the mouse down and then snap to a certain position. Since there are 20 cubes, I need it to go to the nearest 18 degrees (360/20) so that there is a cube in the same place as in the original circle, just that the whole circle is turned. 
[image]
I have gotten the cubes to rotate together but when I try to snap them to the nearest 18 degrees it snaps to a seemingly random spot. I have tried using different methods and I don’t know where I am going wrong! Please help!

This is my code controlling the rotation and then trying to snap it after the user has let go (the circle is the parent of all the cubes):

```
GameObject circle;

void Update(){
    if (circle != null) { //if the circle has been assigned, rotate it
        circle.transform.Rotate(cam.up, -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSpeed, Space.World);
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {       //if clicked, assign the circle
        circle = this.GameObject.transform.parent;
    }
    if (circle != null && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) { //supposed to snap to the right spot, this is the part that isn't working
        var rotate = circle.transform.rotation.y;
        var newRotate = Mathf.Round((rotate * 360) / 18) * 18;
        if (newRotate > 360) { newRotate -= 360; }
        else if (newRotate < 0) { newRotate += 360; }
        circle.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, newRotate, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I notice you never set `circle` to null, the first `if` will always run even after you let go.

Comment: Perhaps try change the localrotation instead of the rotation? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localRotation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many things seems weird.

- In the code you show, you assign `circle` but you never **use** it. why do you need it?
- Are you rotating the parent of these 20 cubes, because that is what you should do but it is not clear in your code
- You use the y value of a **quaternion** when you do `layer.transform.rotation.y`. Try `layer.transform.eulerAngles.y`.

Comment: Sorry, I changed some of my variables so that it would be more clear and forgot to switch some of the 'layer' s to 'circle' s, I fixed it in the question. Yes, all the cubes are the children of the circle, which is what is being rotated. And I didn't realize that, thank you so much!